# Revert after I pushed to the wrong remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had one master branch, then decided to work on new feature and created branch for it. After I did some stuff I've pushed it to remote. Then I switched to master and continued work on it made some feature. 
And the I tried to push it to remote and got message that I have to pull first as far as:

"hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart."

Inspecting pull gave me info that remote I'm trying to push to contain all changes from "feature" branch. So first guess -- I've pushed to wrong remote branch. But I see featured branch in remotes as well(may be latter I've pushed to right one)

I'm the only one contributor so I have all power to revert anything and etc.
What is best strategy to revert remote branch from last push(I use bitbucket)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't pulled down the remote changes yet, you can just do a force [push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git push origin +master --force
```

This will set the state of the remote master branch (and only the master branch, which is what the + is for) to the state that your local branch is in.

If you've already pulled down the changes and merged/rebased then you'll need to get your local branch into the state you want the remote to be in. You can do this with a [reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

```
git reset --hard <hash of commit you want to be last on master>
```

Then do the force push.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have already committed all the changes, use the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit_id_you_wish_to_reset_your_master_to>
git push --force origin master
```